# Why ld unable to find my shared library?

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I have a custom library called **libtaskres.so** that I installed in */usr/lib/procman*. My Makefile builds my program like this:

```
gcc -c procman.c -o obj/procman.o
gcc -c procman_power.c -o obj/procman_power.o
gcc -c procman_sched.c -o obj/procman_sched.o
gcc obj/procman.o obj/procman_power.o obj/procman_sched.o -o procman -ltaskres
```

But whenever I `make` it, the linker returns the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltaskres
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [procman] Error 1
```

But I did, though, included my library, using `ldconfig`:

```
:$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/procman.conf
/usr/lib/procman

:$ ls /usr/lib/procman/
total 24K
24K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21K 2013-Oct-31 15:06:14 libtaskres.so
```

I checked also:

```
:$ ldconfig -v | grep libtaskres
    libtaskres.so -> libtaskres.so
```

What am I doing wrong? If I add the -L/usr/lib/procman to the linker parameters it seems to find it, but I shouldn't need it, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ld.so.conf` file (and its sub-configs in `ld.so.conf.d`) are for the *runtime* loader, not for the linker.

You still need to use the `-L` options when linking.